# Make two grid items for Material-UI both same height with Flex-box

Tags: html, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have two grid items that I want to make the same height by trying to use flex, however nothing seems to work. I believe I might now be using the Grid element in Material UI correctly. I have tried using the height and width properties as well.

```
  <Paper elevation={10} style={{padding:'1.5em'}}>

      <Grid container direction='row' spacing={2} style={{display:'flex'}}>

          <Grid item style={{height:'100%', width:'50%'}}>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item style={{height:'100%', width:'50%'}}>
          </Grid>

      </Grid>

  </Paper>
```

Answer (score 4):

In material ui you can use `alignItems="stretch"` on the container Grid as you can see in the below code:

```js
<Paper elevation={10} style={{padding:'1.5em'}}>
    <Grid container direction='row' spacing={2} alignItems="stretch">

        <Grid item style={{height:'100%', width:'50%'}}>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item style={{height:'100%', width:'50%'}}>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Paper>
```

And you didn't need to set `style={{display:'flex'}}` because of grid style set it too.

> References:

- https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

Comment: Note that what worked for me was to do `minHeight: '100%'` for each Grid item.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using flex on the parent element, you can try setting `align-items: stretch` on the parent too. This should stretch all children of that element to be the same height. E.g.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: I am using the withStyles method which uses classNames and I have set the parent to col and the children to row like this     row: {
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'stretch'
    },
    col: {
      flex: 1
    } but this still isnt working